# Magento-2 How to fix 'echo' error in magento Marketplace technical review report?

Tags: magento2.2, marketplace

I use echo in the class file in my extension.

Magento marketplace not allow **echo/print_r/eval().**

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Someone suggested me that never echo always return and use log to check the dumpy data.

Comment: Ok, but I use observer and helper and I use an echo in helper file as per my requirement. Any solution ? @SaurabhRanjan

Comment: Plz follow what @prince sir suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per **Coding Standard,** you **should not use echo** in block, helper, Model .. etc. **Instead of** you can create phtml file with your content. And call it in observer like:

```
public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $html = $this->getLayout()
         ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Myclass')
         ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::myfile.phtml')
         ->toHtml();    

    return $html;
}
```

check this file for more details:

https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-buynow/blob/master/Block/Product/ListProduct.php

Comment: Thank you **@prince Patel**. This is very useful for me. Till now it is not work in layered navigation. I will try, if not get any solution than ping you.